# RestKit RKObjectManager:getObjectsAtPath - custom processing

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm experiencing issues with RestKit 0.20 creating duplicates in my database when fetching the list of objects from the server. Objects I've created locally and sent to the server are not updated when the mapping results are saved, but instead are duplicated. I think it is related to this bug:  https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1613, so I am looking for an interim fix as I must ship soon. When the results come back from

```
  [myRKObjectManager getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:params success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
```

can I cull the duplicates from this before executing

```
  [myRKObjectManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&error])
```

? I've dug through the documentation and am not understanding how to cull unwanted inserts.

UPDATE: answers to @Wain:

Setup thus:

```
myRKobjectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

NSError *error;

NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:[RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self databaseFilename]] fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil  withConfiguration:nil options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES} error:&error];

NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

// Create the managed object contexts
[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

// Set up response routing
RKEntityMapping *partyMapping = [Party objectMappingInManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore withCustomerMapping:customerMapping notificationMapping:notificationMapping];

RKResponseDescriptor *partyResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:partyMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"api/allparties" keyPath:@"parties" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:partyResponseDescriptor];
```

Entity class is declared:

```
@interface Party : NSManagedObject<PostRequestDelegate>
```

using the category

```
NSManagedObject (ActiveRecord)
```

Party object is created using

```
Party *newParty = [Party object];
```

and saved in the database via:

```
    [myRKobjectManager.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&error]
```

Mappings used:

```
RKEntityMapping* partyMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Party" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[partyMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                   @"added_date": @"addedDate",
                                                   @"id": @"partyId",
                                                   @"modified_date": @"modifiedDate",
                                                   @"name": @"name",
                                                   }];
partyMapping.identificationAttributes=@[@"addedDate"];
[partyMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"customer" toKeyPath:@"customer" withMapping:customerMapping]];
[partyMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"notification_history" toKeyPath:@"notifications" withMapping:notificationMapping]];
```

Comment: What mappings are you using? Are you working with multiple contexts? How are you saving the locally created objects?

Comment: @Wain  I've updated the post with more setup information. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you creating your own contexts instead of having RestKit create them?

Comment: I copied that from the RestKit code, selector:

        [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

so I am letting RestKit create them, yes.

Comment: So are you setting the date added on the objects you create and saving them? Or you're posting the object?

Comment: Both. It is saved locally then posted to the server. When the response comes back, the party should be updated with the partyId & modifiedDate from the server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47451/discussion-between-wain-and-janene-pappas)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your identificationAttributes to your partyId? I'm assuming that is the unique attribute for each of your party objects. Restkit will then check to see if an object with the same partyId already exists in core data and update it instead of creating a new object.

Read the "Entity Identification"  section from the documentation at http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html for more details on how this works.